# Github pages responds with 404 error for three.js canvas and imports

Tags: javascript, three.js, github-pages, react-three-fiber

When trying to host my webpage with a three.js background, everything loads properly when hosted locally but as soon as I push it up to github pages nothing loads - just html.

I am using vite to package my code, and gh-pages to deploy the 'dist' folder to the hosted branch. I have tried changing the urls of all images and assets to '/image' and storing the images in a public folder inside the root folder, as vite recommends. I run
$ npm run build, and
$ npm run preview
and everything looks good. I run npm run deploy (I added a deploy script in package.json, deploy: 'gh-pages -d dist'), and then host the gh-pages branch on github pages and only the html shows up, and the console shows multiple 404: file not found errors.

[Repo](https://github.com/talmage89/ThreeJSDemo2)

The hosted code is on the gh-pages branch, if that hasn't been clear already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url to your JS and CSS files is wrong.
Your [github page](https://talmage89.github.io/ThreeJSDemo2/) is trying to load the the JS from `https://talmage89.github.io/assets/index.2e5bc2a5.js`...
But it should be:
`https://talmage89.github.io/ThreeJSDemo2/assets/index.2e5bc2a5.js`.

The Vite documentation hss [specific instructions for setting the base when hosting on Github Pages](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages)

Comment: I'm trying to use Jekyll to fix it, is this the right approach? Is there a simpler way to go about fixing this?

Comment: You seem to be building with Vite but no vite.config.js? Vite seems to have a "base" [config setting](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base). Maybe using that instead of the base tag in your html will work. I have never used Vite btw, I am just looking at the docs.

Comment: Perfect, that finally fixed it. I configured the base path with 

"npx vite build --base=/ThreeJSDemo2/"

and it fixed it, website is now up and running.